# Twitter bootstrap not displaying right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm looking for this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms the Inline form `.form-inline`

Now on my page the inputs look wired like they have no padding:

Live example: here: http://jsbin.com/ariret/1/edit

Here is my code:

```
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('login'); ?>" id="form-login" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="email" name="email-login" placeholder="<?=$this->translate('Email');?>">
            <input type="password" class="input-small" id="password" name="password-login"  placeholder="<?=$this->translate('Password');?>">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="keep-logged" value="1" id="check-logged"> <?=$this->translate('Remember me'); ?>
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="login_type" value="normal" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn"><?=$this->translate('Login');?></button>
          </form>
        </div><!-- end navbar-iner -->
      </div><!-- end navbar -->
```

And here is, how it looks like:

[image]

It needs to have the same height as the login button.
I have the css and js files included on my page!

Comment: Do you have any custom css that is affecting your inputs?  This is hard to debug with only seeing the html.  A link to your project would be helpful.

Comment: Great question! Here's a jsbin link that reproduces the problem: http://jsbin.com/ariret/1/edit

Comment: @Jrod no, as you can see here: http://jsbin.com/ariret/1/edit thx w0lf

Comment: A test link will be useful to help you better .

Comment: @Shail updated my post Sir: http://jsbin.com/ariret/1/edit

Comment: check here .. works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/shail/BB8ns/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a JSbin bug with Bootstrap. Other test sites (and local host) show this to work as expected.

Bootstrap is setting the height of the input fields to 20px, yet it is not getting applied. The answer is not clear, but you can always head over to https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/new and file a new Issue.

Comment: Well, it just removes the marin-bottom of the form, the inputs still don't change! like in the bootstrap page example

Comment: If it needed this class, it would have been shown in the [respective](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) page

Comment: Hmm it looks like the dropdown arrows, aren't taking the height right, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns `.btn-small`

Comment: Maybe it's JSBin + Shadow DOM.

Comment: Its a jsbin issue .. and we can create the form with form-inline as well

Comment: I have added class `span4` with the class `input-small` and also tried without `input-small` it only changes the width, the height doesn't change :(

Comment: 20px issue on JSBin threw me too! Thanks to @Joshua for clearing that up.

Comment: I will override the css manually like I did before, I thought there is a better solution to this, thank you a lot for your time

Comment: @Uffo the solution is NOT to use JSBin because it's being buggy.

Comment: ... that said don't get me wrong: JSBin is an excellent tool, however for some reason, in this case, something's borked.

Answer (score 1):

"*It needs to have the same height as the login button. I have the css and js files included on my page!*"

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">login</button>
```

will reduce the height of the button to (almost) the height of the inputs

If you want to increase the height of the inputs to align the button, I suggest you locally override the css

```
<style type="text/css">
.form-inline .input-small {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
</style>
```

both "solutions" works in the jsbin example - http://jsbin.com/ariret/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following way :

Jsfiddle [Working inline bootstrap form](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/BB8ns/3/)

Result in browser [Jsfiddle in browser](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/BB8ns/3/show)

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="nav row-fluid">

                        <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="email or username" />
                            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                            <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="keep-logged" value="1" id="check-logged"> <?=$this->translate('Remember me'); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="login_type" value="normal" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">login</button>
                        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```